# Compiling MPIR with Visual C++ 2010

Tags: gmp, visual-c++-2010

I'm trying to compile MPIR (the Windows-friendly fork of GMP) from the command line. My setup is pretty bog standard, Windows Vista 32-bit, Visual C++ 2010 express edition, and I'm just going for a completely vanilla 32-bit static library build, not trying to use the IDE. The information I could find with a Google search says:

1. Install the appropriate version of yasm.
2. Go into build.vc10
3. Configure.bat
4. Make.bat

I managed to get as far as step 3 seeming to work, and past the first obstacle in step 4, but now it's tripping up on this line in make.bat:

```
%MS_BUILD% gen-mpir\gen-mpir.vcxproj /p:Platform=Win32;Configuration=Release
```

As far as the searches I've run can determine, there is no gen-mpir anywhere in the entire directory tree, nor any other reference to such. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer from the good folk on the mpir-devel mailing list: http://groups.google.com/group/mpir-devel/browse_thread/thread/488233bc8face88a